# Real analysis continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and that $$
\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x)=\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x) =k$$ Prove that $f$ is bounded and if there exist a point $x_0 \in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_0)>k$, then $f$ attains a maximum value on $\mathbb{R}$.

I know a function $f:D\to\Bbb R$  is said to be bounded if there exists a constant $C>0$  such that $|f(x)|\leq C $ for all $x\in D$ but I am not seeing how I can prove $f$ is bounded only knowing the limits and that it is continuous.

Is there any one definition I should be considering when trying to prove this? Any thoughts or hints?

Comment: What are your thoughts so far? What has been giving you trouble?

Comment: draw a possible picture of $f$ on paper and try to visualise

Comment: Please show more effort.

Comment: I know a function f:D→R is said to be bounded if there exists a constant C>0 such that |f(x)|≤C for all x∈D but I am not seeing how I can prove f is bounded only knowing the limits and that it is continuous.

Comment: @Pedro "Please tell your thoughts..." Right. "...and accept an answer in the end." Well, not necessarily.

Comment: True, I should have added, accept an answer in the end if it is an answer that helped you out, or was the most helpful (when there were multiple answers)

Comment: @Pedro Why do you see fit to mention this systematically (it seems)? I can think about several other advices more helpful than to "accept an answer in the end"... (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Comment: @Did Since I find it important, people deserve credits for their well written answers. Also, some new people tend to forget this. The first question I wrote on stackoverflow I also forgot this, people on stack overflow pointed me out that I needed to accept an answer, and I am glad they told me not to forget that.

Comment: @Pedro To me, this recommendation puts emphasis on a minor aspect of the whole process. Putting it on the same level as the request to show some personal input, is misleading, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Contradiction is your best friend in analysis.

Suppose that $f(x)$ is not bounded. Then for all $C>0 \in \mathbb{R}$, there is an $r \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $| f(r) | > C$. Let $C = \frac{1}{ \epsilon}$ for $\epsilon > 0$. Then for all $\epsilon > 0$, $|f(r)|>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$. Thus, there exists an $r_0$ such that $|f(r_0)| > \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{\epsilon} = \infty \implies f(r_0) = \pm \infty$. But this means that $f$ is not continuous (because it has an infinite discontinuity) and therefore, by contradiction, $f$ must be bounded.

Now, because $f$ is bounded, there are two values $A, B \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $A \leq f(x) \leq B$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and there are $a, b \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm \infty\}$ such that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = A$ and $\lim_{x \to b} f(x) = B$ (this just means that $a$ and $b$ could be $\pm \infty$, such as in the case where $A = k$). However, note that $B \geq f(x_0) > k$ so $B \neq k$. Thus, $b \neq \pm \infty$ and so $b \in \mathbb{R}$. By continuity, $f(b) = \lim_{x \to b} f(x) = B \geq f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore $f(b) \geq f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and so $f(b)$ is a maximum of $f$.