# Real analysis Limits and continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and that $$
\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x)=\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x) =k$$ Prove that $f$ is bounded and if there exist a point $x_0 \in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_0)>k$, then $f$ attains a maximum value on $\mathbb{R}$.

Edit by non OP. The OP seems to be a new user that posted the same question twice in less than 2 hours, both on MSE.
[Real analysis continuous functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1195754/real-analysis-continuous-functions)

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fact that a continuous function on a compact set is bounded and attains it's maximum?

Comment: What is the definition of a "compact set" I am not familiar with that term.

Comment: Break $\mathbb R$ up into $A=(-\infty,-n)$, $B=[-n,n]$ and $C=(n,\infty)$.  Choose $n\in\mathbb N$ big enough so that the function is less than $k+1$ on $A\cup C$.  And $f$ is bounded on $B$ because it's compact (which just means closed and bounded).

Comment: A compact set in R is a set that is closed and finite.

Comment: @NoySoffer Your definition of a compact set is incorrect. While finite sets are indeed compact, there are many infinite sets that are also compact, e.g. the closed interval $[0,1]$. Obviously you meant that a compact set in R is one that is closed and *bounded*, but you should be more careful when you explain things to people that cannot catch your mistakes because they were not aware of the correct definition to begin with.

Comment: you have posted the same question twice in less that 2 hours, and this is very definitely not the right thing to do. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1195754/real-analysis-continuous-functions Be welcome to MSE, please learn the rules. Also, as some comments on the other question suggest, consider accepting answers that you find correct (that would bring points to the person that answered the question, as well as to you, and would let others know the question has indeed been answered satisfactorily). When you get more point you may also vote any answers (to any questions) up or down.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ has finite limits at the infinities:

$\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists M_1, M_2>0: \forall x>M_1, \forall x<-M_2, |f(x)-k|<\varepsilon$

Therefore, we can see that in the sections $(M_1, \infty), (-\infty, -M_2)$, $f$ is bounded due to the definition of the limit (from $|f(x)-k|<\varepsilon$.

In addition, let's note that $[-M_2, M_1]$ is a compact set, and therefore, according to Weierstrauss's theorem, $f$ is bounded in that section and receives a minimum and maximum.

From here, I'll let you figure out the second section just for the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Both proofs are similar and could be done assuming the opposite and getting a contradiction.

So, first assume $f$ was not bounded. Then (without loss of generality, replacing $f$ with $-f$ if necessary) we may pick points $a_n$ such that $f(a_n)>n$. This sequence 
of $a_n$ must be bounded for otherwise it would contain either a sequence that goes to $\infty$ or a sequence that goes to $-\infty$, but in the former case, say 
$a_{n_j}\to\infty$ as $j$ goes to $\infty$ we get a contradiction since 
$f(a_{n_j})\to\infty$ but it is supposed to be that $f(a_{n_j})\to k$. If 
$a_{n_j}\to-\infty$ we get a similar contradiction. So, 
the sequence $a_n$ is bounded, and hence we may pick a converging subsequence, 
say $a_{n_m}\to x$ for some $x$, as $m\to\infty$. But then the contradiction is that 
$f(a_{n_m})\to\infty$ as $m\to\infty$, and by continuity at the same time 
$f(a_{n_m})\to f(x)<\infty$.

For the other part assume that $f(x_0)>k$ for some $x_0$. We already proved that 
$f$ is bounded, so we could define $M=\sup\{f(t): t\in\mathbb R\}<\infty$. Then there is a sequence $b_n$ such that $f(b_n)>M-\frac1n$. The sequence $b_n$ must be bounded, 
for otherwise we could pick a subsequence $b_{n_j}$ that either goes to $\infty$ or to $-\infty$, as $j\to\infty$. But that would be a contradiction, as 
$f(b_{n_j})\to M$ as $j\to\infty$, and at the same time $f(b_{n_j})\to k$ with 
$k<f(x_0)\le M$. So, the sequence of the $b_n$ is bounded and we may pick a converging subsequence $b_{n_m}\to y$ for some $y$, as $m\to\infty$. 
Then by continuity $f(b_{n_m})\to M=f(y)$, so the maximum $M$ is attained at $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, to do this proof constructively you need to know the value $k'$ that $f$ takes on where $k' > k$. Once you know that, choose $M$ so that $|f(x) - k| < |k' - k|$ for all $|x| > M$. Then the maximum occurs on the closed interval $[-M, M]$ and there is a global maximum somewhere there because $[-M,M]$ is compact.